# Randomize characters in string but keep formatting

Tags: string, python-2.7

So I have string such as:

```
id = 'ee9baadc-46bc-4486-a78b-830f5b2bcfc9'
```

How can I go about randomizing the characters of the string, but keeping the dashes in the same location, such as:

```
id2 = '9eebaadc-46bc-4846-7a8b-380f5b2bcf9c'
```

This is what I have currently, but it scrambles the dash locations as well:

```
id2 = ''.join(random.sample(id,len(id)))
```

Comment: Is a string containing, say, a `4` or an `f` in the first part a valid permutation of the example string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can randomize each section and preserve dash locations using `split` (on dashes), `sample` to randomize each sub-list and a couple of `join`s to tie it all back together:

```
from random import sample

id_ = 'ee9baadc-46bc-4486-a78b-830f5b2bcfc9'
id_ = "-".join("".join(sample(s, len(s))) for s in id_.split("-"))
```

Avoid calling variables `id`--it overwrites a builtin function.

Answer (score 0):

```
base_id = 'ee9baadc-46bc-4486-a78b-830f5b2bcfc9'
base = base_id.split('-')[0]
random_base = ''.join(random.sample(base,len(base)))
id = re.sub(r'ee9baadc', random_base, base_id)
```

this will suffice, randomizes first set of chars...if I wanted to, I could iterate on that over the entire string.